# Unit Testing Angular in Natviescript: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, nativescript

Is anyone able to help me with my unit testing issues? I am trying to test with Angular2, so I have the following  `tests/example.ts` file:

```
import {beforeEachProviders, inject} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {CloudService} from "../Shared/Cloud/cloud.service";
import {Login} from "../Components/Dock/Login/login.component";

 describe('1st tests', () => {
    it('true is true', () => expect(true).toEqual(true));
  });

describe('Login Component', () => {
  var _cloudService = new CloudService;
  var login = new Login(_cloudService);
  beforeEachProviders(() => [CloudService]);

  it("Toggles Child Opacity on Click", function() {
    expect(login.google.nativeElement.style.opacity.toEqual(0)); //Check if the counter equals 42.
  });
});
```

If I just have the 1st test, everything runs fine, but with the second (Angular test), I get the following output:

> JS: NSUTR: successfully connected to karma
>
> 17 06 2016 13:39:52.033:INFO [NativeScript / 23 (6.0; Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560)]: Connected on socket /#RVDKwphYh_vDt9dxAAAA with id NativeScriptUnit-6168
>
> JS: NSUTR: downloading http://192.168.101.2:9876/context.json
>
> JS: NSUTR: disregarding second execution
>
> JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?391e45351df9ee35392d2e5cb623221a969fc009
>
> JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e
>
> JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7975a273517f1eb29d7bd018790fd4c7b9a485d5
>
> JS: NSUTR: require script /base/app/tests/example.js?a455c4e9fa5e9b056e0c931845325f514b63be7f from ../../tests/example.js
>
> JS: NSUTR: this.error: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
>
> JS: at ../../tests/example.js
>   17 06 2016 13:39:53.605:WARN [NativeScript / 23 (6.0; Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560)]: Adapter did not report total number of specs.
>   NativeScript / 23 (6.0; Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>
> NativeScript / 23 (6.0; Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560)  ../../tests/example.js at line 0 FAILED
>           reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
>   NativeScript / 23 (6.0; Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560):
>
> Executed 1 of 0 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.114 secs / 0 secs)
>
> JS: NSUTR: completeAck
>
> JS: NSUTR-socket.io: io server disconnect

If I add the line `import "reflect-metadata";` to the file, I get the same result ...

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I thought I'd comment in case anybody else stumbled upon the question.

I've been having this issue and it's been driving me crazy. I found a workaround by adding the transpiled Javascript file pattern to my karma.config. I also had to remove the Typescript file pattern from the karma.config. It's not what I was hoping for, but it's a workaround for other people looking for an answer to this.

Comment: Can you provide your Karma config?

Comment: Second Jonny here, if you still have it. The unit testing examples around nativescript are sparse currently.